# Size of MAT in OpenCV android remain 1920*2560*CV_8UC4

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitmapfactory

I am new to android development to OpenCV. I have an image and I am doing some manipulation on image.I first converted my image into bitmap and then convert that bitmap into MAT like below.

```
    Mat src = new Mat (400, 800, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(4));
    Bitmap myBitmap32 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap_file);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, src);
```

But when I run this, I am getting my mat to be

Mat [ **1920*2560*CV_8UC4**, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x527a5950, dataAddr=0x54262010 ]

So,I am  getting image size 1920x2560.

I want this size to be my original 400x800 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From OpenCV Java docs:

> The output Mat is **always created of the same size as the input Bitmap** and of the 'CV_8UC4' type, it keeps the image in RGBA format.

So, for resizing an image, you should first read the image to a Mat and then use `resize()` (from `Imgproc`):

```
public static void resize(Mat src, Mat dst, Size dsize)
public static void resize(Mat src, Mat dst, Size dsize, double fx, double fy, int interpolation)
```

As you want to shrink an image, it's [recommended](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#resize%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Size%29) to use `CV_INTER_AREA` interpolation.